# Run two applications in Heroku and connect them using the PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, tweepy, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a full-stack web application using Python and Heroku.

There are two apps and they are connected using a common database (Heroku Postgres). The backend app streams live tweets from twitter and stores them in a database. In the frontend plotly-dash app, users can give an input query and the sentiments of the query are displayed in real-time. The app is perfectly running on my local server. But when I try to deploy it in Heroku, I am finding difficulty in deploying the two apps.

Am I supposed to deploy the apps separately using two applications? If so, how can I connect to the common database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I supposed to deploy the apps separately using two applications?

Yes.

Heroku is designed to deploy one service at a time. One application per application.

> If so, how can I connect to the common database?

Create one application with a Heroku Postgres addon, then [add a second application to the existing database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons#using-the-command-line-interface-attaching-an-add-on-to-another-app):

```
heroku addons:attach <heroku-addon-name> -a <app-name>
```